# How do I send an arbitrary number of arguments to a method without using a hash?

Tags: ruby, http, refactoring

I'm working with Curb, a ruby wrapper around cURL.

I want to start by saying that I know methods such as method missing can accept arbitrary number args and a block if defined like so:

```
def method_missing(meth, *args, &block); ... end
```

`*args` is an array of parameters.

Now, I'm trying to refactor my calls to the HTTP GET, POST, etc methods, by doing the following with Curb:

```
req = Curl::Easy.send("http_#{method.to_s}", *args) do |curl| ... end
```

where `args` could be either 1 parameter or 2 parameters, which I'm trying to define as follows:

```
args = [url]
args << data if data
```

But I get an error when I invoke the `Curl::Easy.send` line.

```
both block arg and actual block given
```

here are some examples of the methods I'm trying to access from (https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/master/lib/curl/easy.rb):

```
      def http_get(*args)
        c = Curl::Easy.new *args
        yield c if block_given?
        c.http_get
        c
      end 

      def http_put(url, data)
        c = Curl::Easy.new url
        yield c if block_given?
        c.http_put data
        c
      end

      def http_post(*args)
        url = args.shift
        c = Curl::Easy.new url
        yield c if block_given?
        c.http_post *args
        c
      end

      def http_delete(*args)
        c = Curl::Easy.new *args
        yield c if block_given?
        c.http_delete
        c
      end
```

all of them are set up to take arbitrary number of arguments, except put.
But, really, for `http_get` I only need to pass a URL (with query params in the URL). so, I only want to pass one parametr for `http_get`, and 2 params for the others.

Comment: can you show code that defines `args` before you call Curl?

Comment: I did. `args = [url]`. url is just a string. and then I do `args << data if data` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send x number arguments based on the methods number of parameters. The following will work based on the data given.

````
method_name = "http_#{method.to_s}"
params = Curl::Easy.method(:"#{method_name}").parameters
req = Curl::Easy.send("http_#{method.to_s}", *(args[0..(params.size-1)])) do |curl| ... end```
````

However the error you are presenting is when you send a Proc as an argument and pass a block, so it will do what you are asking, but without the stacktrace to narrow it down, I don't think this will solve your error. ie.

```
irb(main):001:0> def tst(&block)
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> arg = Proc.new { }
=> #<Proc:0x00000002cd6930@(irb):3>
irb(main):004:0> tst(&arg) do
irb(main):005:1* end
SyntaxError: (irb):5: both block arg and actual block given
```

As a side note, #parameters returns something like `[[:rest][:args]]` and :rest means the rest of the arguments so you could always do more inspection of the parameters to provide more fine grained arguments.